# How to find duplicated pairs in a list in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have a list of values

```
l = [1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 2]
```

I would like to extract duplicated pairs/clusters with their indices, e.g., `[(0, 1), (2, 4, 7)]`. Is there a fast way to do so? The length of the list could be >100000.

Update: I tried to construct a `n^2` boolean matrix but that took too much memory.

Comment: What exactly would be the output here? What if an item appears more than two times?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should be able to do this in 1 pass by using some kind of dictionary without issues.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem updated the example. Hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: Are the values in `l` always relatively small integers? If so, is there an upper bound that you can be sure of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tag `pandas`

```
s=pd.DataFrame(enumerate(l))
s[s[1].duplicated(keep=False)].groupby(1)[0].apply(list)
1
1       [0, 1]
2    [2, 4, 7]
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: I wrote an (almost) identical answer :(   except the last bit `.apply(tuple).tolist()`

Answer (score 3):

Use `defaulldict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4]
d = defaultdict(list)  # key - number, value - list of indexes

for i, n in enumerate(l):
    d[n].append(i)  # add index to list for this number n

print(d)
```

Output:

> {1: [0, 1], 2: [2, 4], 3: [5], 4: [6], 5: [3]}

Complexitity will be O(n) here

To filter only duplicated items use:

```
[v for v in d.values() if len(v) > 1]
```

Output:

> [[0, 1], [2, 4]]

Comment: Followed by `[tuple(v) for v in d.values() if len(v) > 1]` to find duplicates only.

Comment: Will this take too much memory when len(list) -> large?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.unique` followed by a list comprehension to get the desired collections of indices:

```
In [29]: l = [1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 2]                                           

In [30]: u, inv, counts = np.unique(l, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)                  

In [31]: [np.nonzero(inv == k)[0] for k in np.where(counts > 1)[0]]                              
Out[31]: [array([0, 1]), array([2, 4, 7])]
```

Here's another method that works if the values in `l` are all relatively small integers:

```
In [40]: l = [1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 2]                                                            

In [41]: al = np.array(l)                                                                        

In [42]: [np.nonzero(al == k)[0] for k in np.where(np.bincount(l) > 1)[0]]                       
Out[42]: [array([0, 1]), array([2, 4, 7])]
```

Answer (score 0):

We want to match the indices against the sequence of that list.After you find each match, reset this parameter to the location just after the match that was found.

> Code

```
list =[1,1,1,3,4,5,5,6,7]

def Duplicate(func,data):
    start = -1
    y = []
    while True:
        try:
            x = func.index(data,start+1)
        except ValueError:
            break
        else:
            y.append(x)
            start = x
    return y

from functools import partial
New= partial(Duplicate, list)

for a in list:
    print(a, New(a))
```

So if we want to do repeated testing for various keys in that list against the same source, we can use functools.partial to create a new function variable, using a "partially complete" argument list.

> Output:

```
1 [0, 1, 2]
1 [0, 1, 2]
1 [0, 1, 2]
3 [3]
4 [4]
5 [5, 6]
5 [5, 6]
6 [7]
7 [8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `np.unique`, `np.flatnonzero` and list comprehension as follows

```
u_val, dupcount = np.unique(l, return_counts=True)
dups = u_val[dupcount > 1]
out = [tuple(np.flatnonzero(l==item)) for item in dups]

In [98]: out
Out[98]: [(0, 1), (2, 4, 7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use groupby:

```
from itertools import  groupby
from operator import itemgetter

[gr for gr in (tuple(e for e, _ in v) for _, v in groupby(sorted(enumerate(l),key=itemgetter(1)), key=itemgetter(1))) if len(gr) > 1]
```

output:

```
[(0, 1), (2, 4, 7)]
```